# Avalon AUC2 converter for Avalon 6? Can I use a USB controller of sorts?

Tags: mining-hardware, avalon

I can not find a single AUC2 converter for the Avalon 6. Canaan.io seems to be extremely uninformative concerning what this thing is and where to get one and it is sold separately from their Avalon 6!

First - do I need it for a single Avalon 6 miner? It seems I do from some instructions on [this website](https://www.eastshore.xyz/tutorial-avalon-6-3-5th-1050w-bitcoin-miner/), search for AUC Controller and you will see it in a picture, though it seems they are calling the AUC a Controller while it is called a Converter by Canaan.

In the linked page it says: "[For AvalonMiner 6 you need an AUC2](https://canaan.io/question/avalon-controller-and-auc/)"

I have searched far and wide to find this "AUC2" converter... I can't find it ANYWHERE! Is there some kind of converter that will take its place, that perhaps I can just update the firmware??

I found that AUC3 is an acronym for "AUC3 ([AvalonMiner USB Convertor](https://canaan.io/product/avalonminer-741/) 3)" but I can't find this for sale anywhere either!

I have found a [lead](https://github.com/Canaan-Creative/Avalon-USB-converter) That somehow these are indeed some kind of controller which has updateable firmware. I am wondering if this indeed the case and more specifics on which type of converter I need i.e. does it have to be both a USB2IIC & USB2UART converter as the above website says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its very hard to get your hands on AUC2 converters we have written a Guide on how to run the Avalon6 without an AUC2 converter, see below link:
https://www.cryptouniverse.at/run-avalon-6-miner-without-auc2-converter/
cheers

Comment: While that link might contain useful information, it would be better if you could edit your answer to summarize the important points from the page in case it goes down :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need an AUC to run any avalon miner.  AUC3's will work on AV6.  But AUC2's will NOT work on AV741.

I've been looking for a spare as well and have tried a few generic USB2I2C devices from china with no luck.  I'm just not that skilled with these sorts of things.